# "Attempting to use incompatible return type" with class implementing Serializable

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

I have the following interface:

**Slicer**

```
public interface Slicer {
    Optional<Map<String, ? extends Serializable>> pointer();
}
```

of which I have an implementation:

**DynamoDbSlicer**

```
public abstract class DynamoDbSlicer implements Slicer {

    @Override
    public abstract Optional<Map<String, AttributeValue> pointer();
}
```

where `AttributeValue` is from the AWS SDK and defined as:

```
public final class AttributeValue implements SdkPojo, Serializable, ToCopyableBuilder<AttributeValue.Builder, AttributeValue> {
```

Note that it implements `Serializable`.

I am getting a compiler error on the abstract method in `DynamoDbSlicer`:

```
pointer() in DynamoDbSlicer clashes with pointer() in Slicer; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

What am I missing?

Comment: According to [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) Can you try to use `super` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, this looks like it should compile, because Java (since 1.5) has had return type covariance.  This means that an overriding method can declare a return type that is a subtype of the original method's return type.

It looks like `Optional<Map<String, Serializable>>` is a subtype of `Optional<Map<String, ? extends Serializable>>`, but it's not.  Interestingly, if you remove the `Optional` part from both return types, this compiles.

```
interface Slicer {
    Map<String, ? extends Serializable> pointer();
}
abstract class DynamoDbSlicer implements Slicer {
    @Override
    public abstract Map<String, Serializable> pointer();
}
```

It compiles because `Map<String, Serializable>` is a subtype of `Map<String, ? extends Serializable>` -- one can assign an instance of the former to a variable of the latter type.

However, adding `Optional` makes it fail to compile for the same reason that [a `List<Dog>` isn't a `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po) -- generics are invariant.  In this analogy, `Dog` is like the specific subtype that matches `Map<String, Serializable>`, and `Animal` is like the general type that matches `Map<String, ? extends Serializable>`.  Just like a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`, a `Optional<Map<String, Serializable>>` is not a `Optional<Map<String, ? extends Serializable>>`.

The easiest way of getting this to compile without removing the `Optional` bit is to match the type exactly.

```
abstract class DynamoDbSlicer implements Slicer {
    @Override
    public abstract Map<String, ? extends Serializable> pointer();
}
```

If this doesn't fit your requirements, then you'll need to create a type parameter on the interface that your class can supply as a type argument.

```
interface Slicer<T extends Serializable> {
    Optional<Map<String, T>> pointer();
}
abstract class DynamoDbSlicer implements Slicer<AttributeValue> {
    @Override
    public abstract Optional<Map<String, AttributeValue>> pointer();
}
```

The type parameter allows this to compile.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think I can make the code work without the optional

Comment: In the "interestingly" section, by "remove the Optional part" I meant a return type of `Map<String, ? extends Serializable>` in the interface and `Map<String, AttributeValue>` in the class would compile.